# Adding a dropdown box on top of content from an existing jQuery accordion dropdown that pushes content down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, accordion

I am trying to find a way to have a second-level dropdown menu lay on top of the content below a [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) [accordion](/questions/tagged/accordion) style dropdown menu. The jQuery accordion style dropdown purposely pushes down the content below; however, I do not want the second-level dropdown to push the content down. Is there any solution to do this?  I don't care if it's more jQuery, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [css](/questions/tagged/css), [php](/questions/tagged/php), what-have-you.

The main navigation on this page is what I'm trying to find a solution for: [jQuery accordion dropdown that pushes content down and needs a "hover over content" dropdown box added to 2nd-level](http://www.kmymca.org/2011-Stage/index3.html)

Comment: Browsing the unanswered questions I saw this one, but the link no longer exists. Did you find an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the code, the only solution I can think of is to set the second-level dropdown to `position:absolute`. Remember to set the `z-index` to a value higher of that of the accordion.